# SQL query return null results yet there are values in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a certain report that requires joining two tables and creating a sub queries. Below is the code

```
WITH temp_ticket_rows (client_id, last_name,first_name, pet_name) AS 
(   
    SELECT 
        C.fldClientID, C.fldLastName, C.fldFirstName, P.fldName     
    FROM 
        [OneTwoThreePet].[dbo].[tblPets] P   
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
        tblClients C ON P.fldClientID = C.fldClientID
),  temp_tips ([Last Name], [First Name], [Pet Name]) AS 
( 
    SELECT  
        C.fldLastName, C.fldFirstName, 
        (STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + P.fldName[text()]
                FROM [OneTwoThreePet].[dbo].[tblPets] P
                WHERE P.fldClientID = C.fldClientID 
                  AND p.fldInactive IN ('0','')
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2,' ')) AS [Pet Name]   
    FROM 
        temp_ticket_rows P
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        tblClients C ON C.fldClientID = P.client_id
) 
SELECT
    UPPER(LEFT([Last Name], 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING([Last Name], 2, LEN([Last Name]))) AS [LAST NAME],
    UPPER(LEFT([First Name], 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING([First Name], 2, LEN([First Name]))) AS [FIRST NAME],
    [Pet Name] AS [PET NAME],
    COUNT (*) AS [PET NUMBER] 
FROM
    temp_tips 
--WHERE [Pet Name] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY [Last Name], [First Name], [Pet Name] 
ORDER BY [Last Name] ASC
```

The results from above query gives some null which are not supposed to be there since there is value. Below is the results of the query you can see the nulls yet pet number counts to 1

[image: query results]
Changed the structure of the query as below

```
WITH temp_ticket_rows (client_id, last_name,first_name, pet_name) AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        C.fldClientID, C.fldLastName, C.fldFirstName, P.fldName
    FROM
        [OneTwoThreePet].[dbo].[tblPets] P
    INNER JOIN 
        tblClients C ON P.fldClientID = C.fldClientID
), temp_tips ([Last Name], [First Name], [Pet Name]) AS 
( 
    SELECT
        C.fldLastName, C.fldFirstName,
        (STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + P.fldName[text()]
                FROM [OneTwoThreePet].[dbo].[tblPets] P
                WHERE P.fldClientID = C.fldClientID 
                  AND p.fldInactive IN ('0', '')
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ')) as [Pet Name] 
    FROM 
        temp_ticket_rows P
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        tblClients C ON C.fldClientID = P.client_id
)
SELECT
    UPPER(left( [Last Name],1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING([Last Name],2,LEN([Last Name]))) AS [LAST NAME],
    UPPER (left ([First Name],1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING([First Name],2,LEN([First Name]))) AS [FIRST NAME],
    [Pet Name] AS [PET NAME],
    COUNT ([Pet Name]) AS [PET NUMBER]
FROM
    temp_tips 
--WHERE [Pet Name] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    [Last Name], [First Name], [Pet Name]
ORDER BY 
    [Last Name] ASC
```

The results are like this:

[image: query results]

Comment: So, what is expected result?

Comment: as the pet number counts to 1 there should be a pet name  and not null just like the other results

Comment: So you are asking why the PET NAME is null when PET NUMBER > 0?

Comment: exactly and from the table there is no any nulls

Comment: is this the complete query ? i think you missed out the `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 2):

You have used `COUNT (*) AS [PET NUMBER]` so you get the result as 1 even if the `PET NAME` is NULL

Change the `COUNT (*) AS [PET NUMBER]` to `COUNT ([PET NUMBER]) AS [PET NUMBER]` and check. You must get the result as 0 where the `[PET NUMBER]` is null.

Comment: but there is no any null all pet name are there in the pet table

Comment: There is right outer join in query, so due to that you may result where the record in client table exists but matching record in tblPets may not be there so it returns the null value for all such records.

Comment: which join should i use

Comment: If you want exact matching record then use the inner join.

Comment: I have just tried the inner join and nothing has changed

Comment: Try to change " LEFT OUTER JOIN" with Inner join

If possible then share the table structure and sample data so we can identify the problem with query

Comment: check on it now